# Sails Waterline Model attributes Validation type 'integer', 'float' fails

Tags: sails.js, waterline, parseint

My Model Attributes

`per: {
  type: 'float',
  required: true
},
typeid: {
  type: 'integer',
  required: true
},`

My input

`{
  per: '5GH',
  typeid: '6SD',
}`

I expect this should fail and will get error message something like

`typeid: 
   [ { rule: 'integer',
       message: 'undefined should be a integer`

But on validation the o/p after validation

`{
  per: 5,
  typeid: 6,
}`

Do we need to manually validate integer and float in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Official Sails Doc for Validation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations)

As in documentation you can see that integer validation check for integer as well as string for validation.

> According to what i have experienced with validation

For strictly validate use `int`,`decimal` in place of `integer`,`float`

> problem with your scene is as follow.

```
a=5     =>integer in a 
a="5"   =>string but the integer value is 5 
a="5a4" =>string but integer value is 5 not 54

a="a5"  =>string and no integer value.Only this case will fail on validation rule
```

If you want strictly validate the attributes according to you custom rule then you can add **custom validation** rule in your models.See the code below:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type:'string'
        },
        mail: {
            type:'string',
            defaultsTo:'a'
        },
        age:{
            type:'string',
            isInt:true
        }
    },
    types:{
        isInt:function(value){
            console.log(value);
            if(typeof value==='number' && value=== Math.floor(value)){
                console.log('value is a number');
                return true;
            }
            if(!isNaN(1*value)){
                console.log(value);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

So for each model you need to write custom validator.
And

> i guess there is now way currently to write global custom validation
>   rule so that you could apply your validation on attributes of different models by writing validation
>   globally.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome and keep asking!